# Explaining ROC AUC/PR AUC Disparity Between `sklearn` and `tensorflow`

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The code below generates a dummy classification problem and reports ROC AUC and PR AUC implemented both in `sklearn` and `tensorflow`. For some reason I find that each of the two metrics is quite different between the implementations, given the large `num_thresholds=10**6`. I would like to understand why they are not the same.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, average_precision_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# Custom ROC AUC and PR AUC functions using sklearn
def sk_roc_auc(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.py_function(roc_auc_score, (y_true, y_pred), tf.double)

def sk_pr_auc(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.py_function(average_precision_score, (y_true, y_pred), tf.double)

# Create a synthetic dataset for binary classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, 
                           n_informative=10, n_redundant=10,
                           random_state=42)
train_size = int(0.8 * len(X))

X_train, X_test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]

# Create TensorFlow Dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).batch(32)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test)).batch(32)

# Build a simple model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(20,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[
                  tf.keras.metrics.AUC(num_thresholds=10**6, name='tf_roc_auc', curve='ROC'),
                  tf.keras.metrics.AUC(num_thresholds=10**6, name='tf_pr_auc', curve='PR'),
                  sk_roc_auc,
                  sk_pr_auc
              ])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=test_dataset)
```

The above gives me the output below, where the final epoch shows ~0.4% difference in ROC AUC and ~0.4% difference in PR AUC.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Please add `keras.layers.InputLayer` instead of `keras.Input` to Sequential model. `keras.Input` is intended to be used by Functional model.
Epoch 1/10
25/25 [==============================] - 3s 105ms/step - loss: 1.4584 - tf_roc_auc: 0.5420 - tf_pr_auc: 0.6412 - sk_roc_auc: 0.5445 - sk_pr_auc: 0.6624 - val_loss: 1.0316 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.6403 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.7247 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.6841 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.7750
Epoch 2/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 93ms/step - loss: 0.8920 - tf_roc_auc: 0.6683 - tf_pr_auc: 0.7443 - sk_roc_auc: 0.6663 - sk_pr_auc: 0.7518 - val_loss: 0.6263 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.7874 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.8309 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.8122 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.8589
Epoch 3/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 100ms/step - loss: 0.5638 - tf_roc_auc: 0.8010 - tf_pr_auc: 0.8380 - sk_roc_auc: 0.7984 - sk_pr_auc: 0.8401 - val_loss: 0.4561 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.8695 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.8838 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.8818 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9039
Epoch 4/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 90ms/step - loss: 0.4057 - tf_roc_auc: 0.8970 - tf_pr_auc: 0.9068 - sk_roc_auc: 0.8970 - sk_pr_auc: 0.9090 - val_loss: 0.3904 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.9063 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.9039 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.9078 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9163
Epoch 5/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 92ms/step - loss: 0.3344 - tf_roc_auc: 0.9393 - tf_pr_auc: 0.9411 - sk_roc_auc: 0.9414 - sk_pr_auc: 0.9450 - val_loss: 0.3576 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.9251 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.9190 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.9293 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9335
Epoch 6/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 99ms/step - loss: 0.2958 - tf_roc_auc: 0.9573 - tf_pr_auc: 0.9569 - sk_roc_auc: 0.9618 - sk_pr_auc: 0.9628 - val_loss: 0.3364 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.9344 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.9271 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.9373 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9394
Epoch 7/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 95ms/step - loss: 0.2703 - tf_roc_auc: 0.9666 - tf_pr_auc: 0.9658 - sk_roc_auc: 0.9698 - sk_pr_auc: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.3208 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.9403 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.9344 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.9408 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9415
Epoch 8/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 98ms/step - loss: 0.2510 - tf_roc_auc: 0.9719 - tf_pr_auc: 0.9710 - sk_roc_auc: 0.9728 - sk_pr_auc: 0.9727 - val_loss: 0.3087 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.9430 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.9375 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.9319 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9366
Epoch 9/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 95ms/step - loss: 0.2353 - tf_roc_auc: 0.9756 - tf_pr_auc: 0.9747 - sk_roc_auc: 0.9776 - sk_pr_auc: 0.9774 - val_loss: 0.2990 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.9462 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.9417 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.9360 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9418
Epoch 10/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 100ms/step - loss: 0.2217 - tf_roc_auc: 0.9786 - tf_pr_auc: 0.9777 - sk_roc_auc: 0.9820 - sk_pr_auc: 0.9820 - val_loss: 0.2908 - val_tf_roc_auc: 0.9490 - val_tf_pr_auc: 0.9452 - val_sk_roc_auc: 0.9367 - val_sk_pr_auc: 0.9425
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that specifying `sklearn`'s AUC functions like this results in a mini-batch average of the AUC. TensorFlow's metrics however aggregate the confusion matrices and then give the total AUC accurately (given a high value of `num_thresholds`).